# Cannot call method 'substring' of undefined app.js:1 sencha nested

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch-2, jsonp

Cannot call method 'substring' of undefined app.js:1

I get this error on the build package version of a sencha touch app that's based on the [building your first app](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/guide/first_app) tutorial on sencha doc. The regular version runs just fine, but when it is build I Just get a blue screen. The built version runs fine when I comment the proxy related lines for the nestedlist.

```
proxy: {
    type: 'jsonp',
    url: 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&q=http://feeds.feedburner.com/SenchaBlog',
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        rootProperty: 'responseData.feed.entries'
    }
}
```

SOLVED

Most sites claim it is because an xtype is badly written ([example](http://www.levihackwith.com/extjs-4-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-call-method-substring-of-undefined-ext-all-debug-line-4384/)), but, in this case it was due to missing explicit requires of things such as the JsonP, NestedList, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED

Most sites claim it is because an xtype is badly written ([example](http://www.levihackwith.com/extjs-4-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-call-method-substring-of-undefined-ext-all-debug-line-4384/)), but, in this case it was due to missing explicit requires of things such as the JsonP, NestedList, etc.

Comment: What all requires did you add? I added `'Ext.MessageBox','Ext.TitleBar','Ext.NestedList','Ext.data.TreeStore','Ext.data.JsonP'` but still see same error.

Answer (score 0):

Try encoding Urls in urls encodeURI or encodeURIComponent.

This should fix it - if not, please post the whole code of this file.

Did you just forget to add to "leaf" and "fields" infos?

Comment: this is the whole file:  http://pastebin.com/PenQJfw3 I'll look into the encoding.

Comment: The Error is afaik not in the posted Main.js. Ive used it as a replacement for my Main.js an it worked both in dev and as package.

See Screenshot: [link](http://blog.bendspoons.com/externalimages/screenshot.jpg)

Comment: The only thing that really changes is the order, but this is the real app that has that problem http://pastebin.com/TpWVHSgR I got confused and uploaded the wrong file. I'm sorry.

Comment: see screenshot: [link]http://www.zimagez.com/zimage/screenshot-03262013-015132pm.php[/link]