# Sencha Touch - after build package is error?

Tags: sencha-touch

After I build package in command line this:

```
sencha app build package
```

When I put url **localhost/myapp/build/myapp/package**

is not load page and have error message :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'substring' of undefined **app.js**
```

and this my app.js:

```
Ext.Loader.setPath({
    'Ext': 'touch/src'
});
//</debug>

Ext.application({
    name: 'Catalog',
    controllers: [
        'Main','Navigation','searchCon'
    ],
    requires: [
        'Ext.MessageBox'
    ],

    views: [
        'Main' , 'Home' , 'Navigation' , 'Viewport' , 'showSearchCategory' , 'SearchQ'
    ],

    icon: {
        '57': 'resources/icons/Icon.png',
        '72': 'resources/icons/Icon~ipad.png',
        '114': 'resources/icons/Icon@2x.png',
        '144': 'resources/icons/Icon~ipad@2x.png'
    },

    isIconPrecomposed: true,

    startupImage: {
        '320x460': 'resources/startup/320x460.jpg',
        '640x920': 'resources/startup/640x920.png',
        '768x1004': 'resources/startup/768x1004.png',
        '748x1024': 'resources/startup/748x1024.png',
        '1536x2008': 'resources/startup/1536x2008.png',
        '1496x2048': 'resources/startup/1496x2048.png'
    },

    launch: function() {
        // Destroy the #appLoadingIndicator element
        Ext.fly('appLoadingIndicator').destroy();

        // Initialize the main view
        Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('Catalog.view.Main'));
    },

    onUpdated: function() {
        Ext.Msg.confirm(
            "Application Update",
            "This application has just successfully been updated to the latest version. Reload now?",
            function(buttonId) {
                if (buttonId === 'yes') {
                    window.location.reload();
                }
            }
        );
    }
});
```

**Where is wrong code ?**

How do I do for solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

Get used to this error, you'll find it a lot using Sencha. It's usually to do with parsing. Look for characters out of place, such as a comma at the end of a list eg {a,b,c,}.

Possible duplicates:

[Uncaught-TypeError-Cannot-call-method-substring-of-undefined-sencha-touch-all.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16439771/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-call-method-substring-of-undefined-sencha-touch-all-js)

[Cannot call method 'substring' of undefined app.js:1 sencha nested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15642909/cannot-call-method-substring-of-undefined-app-js1-sencha-nested)

See also:

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?263159-Uncaught-TypeError-Cannot-call-method-substring-of-undefined-sencha-touch-all.js-3

Comment: I should try to create app ?

Comment: When I generate new app and try from this.It's not error.
What's happen in my project